# An inequality in a ball in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

Let $B\left(0,R\right)\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be the (open) ball of
radius $R$ with the center at the origin. Let $R'>R.$ I would like to verify that (I am not sure whether it is true or not!) 
$$
\frac{\left|x\left|y\right|-(R')^{2}\frac{y}{\left|y\right|}\right|}{\left|x\left|y\right|-R{}^{2}\frac{y}{\left|y\right|}\right|}\geq\frac{R'}{R},
$$
for any $x,y\in B\left(0,R\right)$ with $y\neq0$.

Could anyone give me a hint?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe you can give us an idea of what you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us make the observation that if $\alpha>0$ then $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{\alpha^2}{x^2}+x^2$ is monotone increasing provided $x>\sqrt{\alpha}$. Fix $x, y \in B(0, R)$ then it follows $\alpha:=|x||y|<R^2$. In particular, it follows
\begin{align}
\frac{\alpha^2}{R'^2} +R'^2 \geq \frac{\alpha^2}{R^2}+R^2
\end{align}
since $R'>R$.

To prove the desired inequality, it suffices to show
\begin{align}
\left| |y|\frac{x}{R'}-R'\frac{y}{|y|}\right|\geq \left| |y|\frac{x}{R}-R\frac{y}{|y|}\right| \ \Longleftrightarrow  \ 
\left|\frac{\alpha}{R'^2}\frac{x}{|x|}-\frac{y}{|y|} \right|^2\geq \frac{R^2}{R'^2}\left|\frac{\alpha }{R^2}\frac{x}{|x|}-\frac{y}{|y|} \right|^2
\end{align}
which is equivalent to 
\begin{align}
\frac{\alpha^2}{R'^2} +R'^2 \geq \frac{\alpha^2}{R^2}+R^2.
\end{align}
Hence we have the desired result.